# Change url for yahoo wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, yahoo

I added a wordpress blog to my yahoo store. I've set it up so the subdomain , blog.domain.com points to the file directory which was /blog. Everything works fine when I go to blog.domain.com but when I start clicking through my site the url changes to site.domain.com I thought creating a subdomain would fix this but it didn't. I want to keep the URL address consistent but when I go to settings > general tab and change the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) everything breaks. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify "everything breaks"? What error do you get when you change the URLs on the General tab?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress stores the URL of the blog in the database at install-time. If you change it after-the-fact then you will need to update the database.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL